# How to use the left and right arrow keys in the tclsh interactive shell?

Tags: tcl

Why can't I use the left and right arrow keys (actually, the same goes for the up and down keys as well) to move about the line I'm currently on in the `tclsh` interactive shell? If I try to press either one, I get a bunch of abracadabra instead of moving back and forth. This is not all that convenient when, for example, you make a typo, but you can't move the cursor back to change it. You have to use the backspace key to erase all the stuff that you've typed after the place where the typo is located thereby destroying all your work. Is it possible to fix this, quite frankly, buggy behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Use `readline`...

Comment: What is that and how exactly do I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality appears to be provided by the `tcl-tclreadline` package. From `apt-cache show tcl-tclreadline`:

> ```
> Description-en_CA: GNU Readline Extension for Tcl/Tk
>  tclreadline adds GNU Readline support to standard Tcl/Tk.  It provides
>  interactive command editing and history for Tcl shells (this must be
>  enabled on a user-by-user basis) and allows the use of GNU Readline
>  features in Tcl programs.
> ```

Once you have installed the package, either from the Software Center or via the command line using `sudo apt-get install tcl-tclreadline`, you can enable it for interactive tcl shells by adding

```
if {$tcl_interactive} {
  package require tclreadline 
  ::tclreadline::Loop
}
```

to your `$HOME/.tclshrc` file as explained on the [tclreadline project homepage](http://tclreadline.sourceforge.net/).